# Camera distance relative Text Mesh Size

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am searching a fromula that can maintain my text mesh size according to the distance from camera. I want that no matter my camera is near or far from text mesh my text show always with same width an height. I have tried this but the problem is still persist somehow

```
float  size = (activeCam.transform.position - transform.position).magnitude;
            newLocalScale = new Vector3(size / 108, size / 108, size / 108);
            transform.localScale = newLocalScale;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the World To Screen Space and Screen To World Space methods to keep the size of all text meshes constant with this code (attach the script to all text mesh objects of course):

```
public Camera activeCam;
public float sizeOfText = 20;

void Update () {
    Vector3 textScreenSpace = activeCam.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    Vector3 adjustedScreenSpace = new Vector3(textScreenSpace.x + sizeOfText, textScreenSpace.y, textScreenSpace.z);        
    Vector3 adjustedWorldSpace = activeCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(adjustedScreenSpace); 
    transform.localScale = Vector3.one * (transform.position - adjustedWorldSpace).magnitude;
    transform.rotation = activeCam.transform.rotation;      
}
```

Edit: there's another way to obtain the same result, using a `Plane`, it's on the Unity Wiki - http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/CameraRelativeScale

Comment: Forgot to add the line to keep the text meshes always parallel to the camera, my bad.